# Refer to and change the caption of a Label without using the Label's Name?

Tags: vba, label

I want to Change the captions of several Label boxes. The Labels are sequentially named (DAY1, DAY2, DAY3...DAY14). I need help finding a way to do this;

```
   DAY1.Caption = "1"
```

without implicitly using the label name...more like:

```
   ("DAY" & i).Caption = 1
```

Where i is an integer. I get a variety of error. My guess is that I don't know the proper object variables or syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular language?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is in the context of VBA (please edit your question to add the "VBA" tag if so). A nice solution would be to retain a reference to your labels as you create them. You can programmatically create a list of labels like this:

```
Dim label As Label
Dim dayLabels As New List(Of Label)
For i = 1 To 7
  Set label = UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Day" & i, True)
  dayLabels.Add(label)
  With label
    .Caption = "Day" & i
    .Left = 10
    .Width = 50
    .Top = 10 * i
  End With
Next
```

Note that you need to show your UserForm as `vbModeless` to use this code. Also note that the positioning of the labels is accomplished with the `.Top` and `.Left` fields; I am using the `.Top` to value to avoid overlapping of the controls (but you could also use `.Left`, for example, to distribute them horizontally).

Now that you have all label references stored in the list, you can simply refer to them by index like you were originally trying to do:

```
dayLabels(3).Text = "The text to appear on Day3 label"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like where your heads at. I run into two problems. Access VBA registers a compile error for

```
Dim daylabels As New List(Of Label)
```

If I remove that line, VBA doesn't recognize any object(s) in line 4;

```
set label = Userform.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1, "Day" & I, True
```

I realize I didn't specify that I was using VBA for Access. I tried playing with the wording. Excel has Userforms but Access treats forms differently...no luck. Here is the full Sub I am using;

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()

Dim DURATION As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Label

DURATION = ((END_DATE.Value) - (START_DATE.Value)) + 1
i = 1

For i = 1 To DURATION
Set x = UserForm.Comtrols.Add("Forms.Label.1", "DAYx" & i, True)
With x
    .Caption = "Day" & i
    .Left = 10
    .Width = 50
    .Top = 30 + (10 * i)
End With
Next
```